# Paypal smart button without billing address?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using PayPal Smart Payment Buttons to enable payments on my website.
I managed to disable the shipping address fields, but I can't disable the billing address.

From what I've seen most of the sites that accept online payments don't require billing address or any information except for the credit card details and the name of the card holder.

Why does PayPal require to enter billing address and is there a way to disable it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Billing fields are used for payment processing by PayPal, as they are necessary for communication with credit card companies for example. They are not returned to you or included as part of the transaction that you see. You cannot remove them.

Most websites that directly collect credit card information, also collect a billing address. It is relatively uncommon to process cards online without a billing address, especially in countries that use address verification (AVS) responses from credit card processors/issuers, since doing so without the billing address is less secure (no address verification can take place) and so more prone to fraud.

Comment: This makes no sense. Any other checkout page I use on internet don't require me to provide email or adress or whatever. I really wish Paypal would enable us to remove this. Also, I don't like forcing clients to provide personal information to third parties. This goes against the RGPD rules in UE.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling is not directly supported due to PayPal's security and verification processes. PayPal generally requires an address for credit card payments in order to comply with anti-fraud and customer verification policies.

You can only disable Shipping Address:

```
<PayPalButtons 
  createOrder={(data, actions) => {
   return actions.order.create({
      ...
      application_context: {
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
      }
   });
 }}
```

/>